# How does ARGV get processed in Perl if I pass two sets of values to it?

Tags: perl, shell, command-line-arguments

If I use `./test.pl file1 file2`, I know the values are stored in `@ARGV` as first and second value, such that `$ARGV[0]` equals `file 1` and so on.

However if I pass the command as `./test.pl ./folder1/* ./folder2/*` where each folder has 1000 numbered files, how is `@ARGV` numbered?

---

I edited to correct the error in question. $ARGV[1] should be file2, instead of file1 as pointed out in the answers and comments.

Comment: `@ARGV` is ordered *exactly* the same way as the parameters are given to it.  Now if your asking in what order your shell expands out the wild cards just before it calls perl, then that's a question about the shell of your choice. You may want to replace `./test.pl` with `echo` and see how it works...

Comment: _`$ARGV[1]` equals `file 1`_ is wrong. `$ARGV[0]` equals `file 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ARGV[0]` is the `first value`, so `$ARGV[0]` is `./folder1/0001` and `$ARGV[1]` is `./folder1/0002` and soforth.  `$ARGV[1000]` would be `./folder2/1001`

(Assuming your files were named `0001` through `1001`)

Comment: Not all shells will be able to expand an argument list that long.

Comment: Good point.  On my Mac, getconf ARG_MAX returns 262144 and on an Ubuntu machine here I see getconf ARG_MAX returns 2097152

Comment: `bash` *is* remarkably flexable.  Pitty the poor folks who are stuck with `cmd.exe`

Answer (score 3):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
use Data::Dumper;

print Dumper @ARGV;
```

**Example 1**

```
./example.pl file1 file2
```

output is

```
$VAR1 = 'file1';
$VAR2 = 'file2';
```

**Example 2**

```
./example.pl folder1/* folder2/*
```

output is

```
$VAR1 = 'folder1/file1';
$VAR2 = 'folder1/file2';
$VAR3 = 'folder1/file3';
$VAR4 = 'folder1/file4';
$VAR5 = 'folder1/file5';
$VAR6 = 'folder2/file1';
$VAR7 = 'folder2/file2';
....
```